# PHP - stop the notice/error displaying at wrong time

Tags: php

I accidentally deleted my previous question about this.

I'm new at PHP. This is my first assignment.  I have an error message "Sales price must be a valid amount" that is being displayed next to the first input box that shouldn't be there. This occurs when the user clicks "confirm" without data in the inputs. Instructions state that in this case, the user remains on the page.  I don't need any error messages displaying at this time.  How can I keep my error messages working as they should but stop the one message from showing up when "confirm" is clicked with no input?  Hope this makes sense.

```html
// get the data from the form
$sales_price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sales_price', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
$discount_percent = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'discount_percent', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
$total_price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'total_price', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);


if (isset($_POST['confirmSubmit'])) {
    echo 'Validation Error';
    $validation_error = 'Validation Error';
}

// validate sales price
$sales_valid = true;
$sales_priceError = '';
if ($sales_price === NULL) {
    $sales_priceError = '';
    $sales_valid = false;
} else if ($sales_price === FALSE) {
    $sales_priceError = 'Sales price must be a valid amount';
    $sales_valid = false;
} else if ($sales_price <= 0.0) {
    $sales_priceError = 'Sales price must be greater than 0';
    $sales_valid = false;
}

// validate discount percent
$discount_valid = true;
$discount_percentError = '';
if ($discount_percent === NULL) {
    $discount_percentError = '';
    $discount_valid = false;
} else if ($discount_percent === FALSE) {
    $discount_percentError = 'Discount percent must be a valid amount';
    $discount_valid = false;
} else if ($discount_percent <= 0.0) {
    $discount_percentError = 'Discount percent must be greater than 0';
    $discount_valid = false;
}


// calculate the discount and the discounted price
$discount_amount = $sales_price * $discount_percent / 100;
$total_price = $sales_price - $discount_amount;

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Quote</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quote.css">
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <h1>Price Quotation</h1>
    <form id="priceForm" name="priceForm" method="post" action=''>
        <label for="sales_price">Sales Price </label>
        <input type="text" id="sales_price" name="sales_price" required
               value="<?php echo $sales_price; ?>"/>
        <?php if (!empty($sales_priceError)) : ?>
            <span style="color:red;background-color: white">
                    <?php echo $sales_priceError; ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label for="discount_percent">Discount Percent </label>
        <input type="text" id="discount_percent" name="discount_percent" required
               value="<?php echo $discount_percent; ?>"/>
        <?php if (!empty($discount_percentError)) : ?>
            <span style="color:red;background-color: white">
                    <?php echo $discount_percentError; ?>
                </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <p class="discount">Discount
            Amount <?php echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$' . number_format($discount_amount, 2); ?></p>
        <p class="total">Total Price <?php echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$' . number_format($total_price, 2); ?></p>
        <input type="submit" class=inline name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Calculate"/>
    </form>


    <form id="confirmForm" name="confirmForm" method="post" action="<?php echo(($sales_valid && $discount_valid) ? 'confirm.php' : ''); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="sales_price" name="sales_price" value="<?php echo $sales_price ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="discount_amount" name="discount_amount" value="<?php echo $discount_amount ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="total_price" name="total_price" value="<?php echo $total_price ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" class=inline name="confirmSubmit" id="confirmSubmit" value="Confirm"/>
    </form>
    <div>
        <p> Enter price and discount amount and click Calculate</p>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably need to check which form is submitted as you have 2 of them.  I don't know what you mean by `user clicks "confirm"` there is no field with that name, do you mean when you submit the second form?

Comment: The first page (index.php) has two buttons.  A "calculate" and a "confirm" button.   The instructions tell me that when the user clicks "confirm" with blank input boxes, they should remain on the page. When the user enters data, the calculate button computes the data, the confirm button takes them to a second page where the data is repeated. This works but I'm getting an alert next to one of the input boxes that shouldn't be there - when the user clicks the confirm button with no data entered.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm so new at this, it is a challenge to accurately describe my problem.

Comment: You need to check `isset($_POST['submitButton'])` around the code that should only run for that button/form.  Personally I would add another hidden field to both forms and put a name like mode on it, and then set the value different and check that instead.  It's possible to submit the form without using the button with JS, for example.  But that is me, and it may be sufficient to just use the button.

Comment: in your code you should have `if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])) { ..do that form..}else if(isset($_POST['confirmSubmit'])){ ..do the other form .. }`  This way it's all nice and neat.  You cant submit both forms at the same time, so why run the code for both.  IN your code I don't know what belongs where, so I cant really give you a working example (well I could, but I am to lazy to figure that much out)

Comment: I give you an example in an answer, but there is too much shared data beween them.

Comment: I will try this now and see if the error message disappears. Thank you for taking the time to help. I don't quite understanding your suggestion about the hidden fields (frustrating, I have such a limited understanding at this point) And we aren't allowed to use JS at all on this assignment.

Comment: The error message remains ... though I could have made a mistake when I followed your suggestion with the if(isset..).

Comment: @Vienne see my answer. Is what you need really.

Comment: @GeneCode  I'm not allowed to use JS.  The assignment must be completed using PHP and HTML only, per the Professor's request.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you need to structure you form processing logic like this:

```
 $sales_price = ''; //default value
 //other fields - I used just this one, but obviously you should do the
 //same/simular for the rest of them

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    //do stuff common to both form, such as both have sales_price

    $sales_price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sales_price', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);

    if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])) {
       //code specific to the first form

       $sales_valid = true;
       $sales_priceError = '';
       if ($sales_price === NULL) {
           $sales_priceError = '';
           $sales_valid = false;
       } else if ($sales_price === FALSE) {
           $sales_priceError = 'Sales price must be a valid amount';
           $sales_valid = false;
       } else if ($sales_price <= 0.0) {
           $sales_priceError = 'Sales price must be greater than 0';
           $sales_valid = false;
       }

        //and so on

    }else if(isset($_POST['confirmSubmit'])){ 
        //code specific to the second form


        if(!empty($sales_price)){
              //do stuff
        }

    }

}
```

This way when the first form is submitted only that code runs, when the second only that code.

When `isset($_POST['submitButton'])` is false its impossible for the validation code to run, and therefor you won't get the error when submitting the other form.  You should check the data in the second forms processing code, to make sure the first one was sent.  You can also add a hidden field (into confirm form) that is empty on the first from submission and then filled after when it is submitted.

*Pro Tip*: is you can use a do/while loop as a control structure in the second form processing code like this:

```
 }else if(isset($_POST['confirmSubmit'])){ 

  do{

    if(empty($sales_price)) break; //bail on the loop


        //form processing code

 }while(false); //runs 1 time
```

Do while, unlike other loops checks the condition (in the while part) after it runs 1 time.  In this case that condition is FALSE, so it ends the loop.  But this allows you to use `break` or `continue` (break is more logical) to exit the loop and prevent the rest of the code from running.  This is cleaner then  excluding the code by if conditions (IMO).

Hope that helps.

*PS - I tried to keep it as simple as I could.*

Answer (score 0):

> This occurs when the user clicks "confirm" without data in the
>   inputs.

Based on your codes, I believe what you really need is a simple `Javascript` form validation prior to submission. You can add this:

```
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {

    // check values
    var salesPriceValue = document.forms["priceForm"]["sales_price"].value;
    if (salesPriceValue.length<=0) {
      alert("Please enter Sales Price before submitting the form!");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script></head>

<body>

<form id="priceForm" name="priceForm" method="post" action='' onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<input type="text" id="sales_price" name="sales_price" required
               value="<?php echo $sales_price; ?>"/>
.. etc
```

The key is `onsubmit` function on the form tag. You can add more form item validation as needed. I just show example of one input text type.

Comment: JavaScript should not be relied on for form validation, it should always be validated on the server as well.  We do JS to be nice to the client so they don't have to re-submit the form.  Javascript errors, and even it's presence ( or the lack of it ) can render it non-functional.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix We should really minimize the client-server interaction as that takes bandwidth on server. Only good data should be submitted to server. Elimination of "empty input" submission is compulsory on properly designed system. Validation on server more towards content checking and not silly mistakes by user (like blank form).

Comment: Javascript is not tagged in the question and in this case we must assume that JS is unknown to the OP `I'm new at PHP. This is my first assignment.`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Sir, HTML is also not tagged in this question.That does not mean one cannot write about html code for OP either. They are all inter related. Importantly answers must points OP to the most efficient and correct way to do things.

Comment: what happens when the page is loaded with no submission?  I can tell you saleprice is NULL and the only reason the OP doesn't have an error in there is this `if ($sales_price === NULL) {    $sales_priceError = '';   $sales_valid = false; }`  Which is actually suppressing an error that should be shown.  With the proper PHP flow control, that entire section can be removed (not to mention none of that should even execute )....  The point is the PHP is less then Ideal, so why mask that with JS.

Comment: Such empty data submission should be prevented at the client side is all I am saying. Your debugging the code is fine.

Comment: In any case, I wasn't saying it's not a valid answer.   I was just saying why allow Bad PHP to exist when this is a PHP assignment.  It seems counter productive to mask that with a language that was never mentioned.  As for HTML, that is integral to PHP and web design.  It is possible to make a PHP site with no JS at all.

Comment: I guess there are pros and cons in both implementations.

Comment: I should have been more clear.  My assignment must be coded only in PHP and HTML.  I cannot use any JS.  This is the first assignment after only a few lectures. The book is worthless, my understanding of PHP is so weak that I'm not even able to apply the recommendations here to fix the issue.  I have to *see* the actual code - the changes I need to make. Reading about what I should do is basically useless to me right now, which is beyond frustrating.

Comment: Ok @Vienne understood. Then the answer by ArtisticPhoenix should be good for you.